# Probability list creation

Tags: python, numpy

following problem: Having a base triple (0,1,0)

Now I try to create a list of changed triples in a given range.

The constraints:

1. triple[0] and triple[2] have should have a maximum of r, such as r=0.2
2. sum(triple) = 1
3. triple[0] needn't to be equals triple[1] and should be increased by a given stepwise-parameter s, such as s= 0.02

In this above mentioned example our methode should create

```
lst = [(0.0, 1, 0.0),(0.02, 0.98, 0.), (0.04, 0.96,0), (0.04,0.94, 0.02), (0.06,0.94,0), (0.06, 0.92, 0.02), (0.06, 0.9, 0.04), ...]
```

Is there any pretty way to do this?

Maybe you have an idea to create these list without nested loops (probably with numpy?).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What have you tried?

Comment: Very complicated in detail but I need this list for a simulation with switching parameters

Comment: You seem to imply constraint of triple[0] > triple[2] .. is that intentional?

Comment: Actually no constraints in this way. I would simply add reversed tuples if not t[0]=t[2] at the end. Its like: decrease the middle and distribute the values arbitrary to the left and right, constrained by s

Comment: Is there any reason to avoid nested loops? It seems like it would be really easy to iterate the first and third values from 0 to r by steps of size s, then calculate the middle value by subtracting them from 1.

Comment: Well it's really easy but I thought python/numpy would offer a pretty solution for this kind of requirements

Comment: You say `r <= c` for some constraint `c`. So can `r` be negative?

Comment: Good objection: No negative values allowed, because its a probability list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a list comprehension that should provide all 3-tuples that meet your constraints (as I understand them). Its a bit more clunky than I'd like due to the range function only accepting integers:

```
r = 0.2
s = 0.02
steps = int(math.ceil(r/s))
lst = [(a*s, 1-(a+b)*s, b*s) for b in range(steps) for a in range(steps)]
```

Results:

```
>>> lst[0:4]
[(0.0, 1.0, 0.0), (0.02, 0.98, 0.0), (0.04, 0.96, 0.0), (0.06, 0.94, 0.0)]
>>> lst[90:94]
[(0.0, 0.8200000000000001, 0.18), (0.02, 0.8, 0.18), (0.04, 0.78, 0.18), (0.06, 0.76, 0.18)]
```

The first and last values only go up to 0.18 in this code, and I'm not sure if that's desirable or not (is the constraint < r or <= r?). It shouldn't be too hard to tweak, if you want it the other way.

Comment: Nice answer! +1 This is what I've called a 'pretty solution'. I've the check if tweak is only: "steps = int(math.ceil(r/s))+1" Thanks a lot

Comment: I think adding 1 unconditionally will wrong if r is not an exact multiple of s. Try "steps = int(math.floor(r/s))+1". That will get you the next higher integer in all cases (even if you already have an integer after the division). Also, apropos of my comment on the question, its worth noting that the list comprehension (with its two "for _ in _" clauses) is equivalent to a pair of nested loops.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that makes the triple as you describe ... something such as:

```
def make_triple(r=0.2, s=0.02):
    element_one = round(random.uniform(0, r), 2)
    max_s = r/s
    element_three = random.randint(0, max_s) * s
    element_two = round(1 - element_one - element_three, 2)
    return (element_one, element_two, element_three)
```

And then just create a single loop that calls this function:

```
list_of_triples = []
for i in range(5):
    list_of_triples.append(make_triple(0.2, 0.02))
```

And there you go!  No nested loops necessary.

Comment: This function looks nice but doesn't fit the given constraints

Comment: I just edited the max_s variable to fit the constrant of the third element being less than r.  Was there another I missed?

Answer (score 1):

Another numpy answer just for kicks:

```
import numpy as np
r = .2
s = .02

a, b = np.mgrid[0:r:s, 0:r:s]
lst = np.dstack([a, 1 - (a+b), b]).reshape(-1, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a NumPy solution without for-loops, as requested. It uses a 3D array and NumPy broadcasting rules to assing the scale by row and by column. `scale` is a 2D array of a single column so it can be conveniently trasposed by `.T`. In the end, the 3D array is reshaped to 2D.

```
import numpy as np

r = .2
s = .02

scale = np.arange(r, step=s, dtype=float).reshape(-1,1)
a = np.empty((len(scale),len(scale),3), dtype=float)
a[:,:,0] = scale
a[:,:,2] = scale.T
a[:,:,1] = 1 - a[:,:,0] - a[:,:,2]

print a.reshape(-1,3)
```